# Some files in /usr/sbin/ are never being replaced?

Tags: filesystem

I've a question concerning a weird issue I never ran into before even though I am working with many servers for quite a long time.

So there is the [cherokee web server](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) that I compiled and installed with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

Before this 'upgrade' I deleted the old version completely (also checked with finding tools) and backed up the existing configuration which I upgraded and copied back to its original folder later.

But the basic problem are two files: **cherokee-worker** and **cherokee-admin**. Those files were not copied into /usr/sbin/ correctly. To prove my suspicion I executed some commands:

```
/home/paul/build/cherokee/cherokee-1.2.1/cherokee/cherokee-worker -i
  >> Version: 1.2.1

cp /home/paul/build/cherokee/cherokee-1.2.1/cherokee/cherokee-worker /usr/sbin/cherokee-worker

/usr/sbin/cherokee-worker -i
  >> Vesion: 1.0.8
```

The same issue happens with **cherokee-admin**. The most weird thing is that if I replace the actual copy of **cherokee-worker** in /usr/sbin/ with a symbolic link to the *working* file in /.../build/../cherokee-1.2.1 it **works**!

```
rm /usr/sbin/cherokee-worker
ln -s /home/paul/build/cherokee/cherokee-1.2.1/cherokee/cherokee-worker /usr/sbin/cherokee-worker
/usr/sbin/cherokee-worker -i
  >> Version: 1.2.1
```

It seems like a hard copy of cherokee-worker/-admin isn't working properly. But how come?

Do you know what happens? I have absolutely no clue what's going on.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Paul

Comment: There is a PPA repo for Cherokee. Makes installing and updating much easier. Just look at their mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be root to run make install. From your question it is not clear whether you have the correct permissions when running it.

You should compile as a normal user, and install as root (also, you should use /usr/local as a prefix for everything that doesn't come from your distribution's package manager, but that's another debate):

```
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously installed cherokee from the ubuntu repositories, then that version was installed in /usr/sbin, and your manually compiled version will probably interfere badly with that 'official' installation.  Make sure to remove the packaged version before trying to install a custom built copy.

```
apt-get remove cherokee
```

As far as it goes, I would recommend always using the version in the repositories unless you have a very good reason.  That way, you will get updates automatically and won't have to fight with upstream bugs yourself. http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/cherokee